# Writing a migration to alter a specific feature within a specific column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app in which we were accidentally counting promotional codes twice instead of once.  I was able to solve the problem in the actual codebase such that it won't happen again, but i'm having a hard time writing a migration to reset all of the old ones.  I don't have a whole lot of experience with writing migrations, let alone altering them, so I decided to just adding one element to each of them first as practice, and then going forward at dividing everything in half.

With my migration I have written. the `promo_codes` is the name of the table, and the `times_used` is what I eventually want to cut in half.

```
class PromoCodeTest1 < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :promo_codes, update_attribute(:times_used + 1)
  end
end
```

Going down this road I end up getting an undefined error with `update attribute`. Would anybody know what I need to do to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen `update_attribute` helper in migrations.

You need just to run SQL query (note - don't use ActiveRecord models, please).

It can look like:

```
  def up
    execute "UPDATE promo_codes SET times_used = times_used / 2;"
  end
```

Maybe you need add some checks if columnd `times_used` can contain `NULL` values or there are odd values...

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I was way off scope a little bit. (i haven't had much experience with sql related things. Thank you so much!)